# How can I check if the environment is WSL from a shell script?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In `.bashrc`, I have some configuration for specific environments like this.

```bash
if [ "$(uname)" = 'Linux' ]; then
   . "$HOME/.bash.d/ubuntu"
fi

if [ "$(uname)" = 'Darwin' ]; then
   . "$HOME/.bash.d/osx"
fi
```

To know whether the current environment is under [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), I use the `/etc/wsl.conf` file that normally only exists in WSL.

```bash
if [ -f "/etc/wsl.conf" ]; then
   . "$HOME/.bash.d/wsl"
fi
```

But of course, the file can also exist in other environments.

How should I check if the current environment is running in WSL?

Comment: `/etc/wsl.conf` doesn't exist on my WSL.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Yes, that's partly why the OP is asking this question !  The file may or may not exist.  For the OP, it's always used on their WSL systems for configuration purposes, but it doesn't exist by default.  However, it would be easy to accidentally create a `/etc/wsl.conf` on a pure-Linux system, causing false-positives.  So the OP was asking for better options.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no "foolproof" way of doing this, since each detection method *could* cause false-positives or false-negatives in certain situations.  That said, if you are just doing this for your personal config files, then you probably have a pretty good idea about whether a given method will work for your system or not.

Some various methods, with their pros and cons:

- The presence of `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop` is a pretty good indicator that you are on WSL.  This *may* be the most reliable method, and it is what Ubuntu's Snapd project uses as its detection mechanism.  This file exists under both WSL1 and WSL2 by default.  Even when Interop is disabled via `/etc/wsl.conf`, this file will still be created by WSL at startup.

  Caveats:  Of course, a `binfmt_misc` entry could be set up with the name `WSLInterop`, but that would be extremely pathologic, leading to a false-positive test.

  Also, it *is* possible to override the name of the Interop, as mentioned in [my Ask Ubuntu answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437112/1165986).  This would be an unusual case, but we used it to thwart the Snapd WSL detection temporarily while a bug was being fixed.  This creates a false negative, of course.

  <sub>In a war of escalation, you *could* "thwart-the-thwarting" by grepping for the `magic 4d5a` in that directory, but that might be going a bit far ;-)</sub>
- As [@MBehrens mentions](https://superuser.com/a/1749792/1210833), the *default* kernel name under WSL contains the string "Microsoft" (or "microsoft", depending on the release).  Using `uname -r` or `/proc/version`) can be used for detection.

  Caveats:  Other systems *may* (I'm thinking Azure) use a Microsoft-built kernel, which could create a false positive.  And it's possible to build a custom kernel for WSL2 with a different name, which would create a false negative.
- You could even just check for the environment variable `$WSL_DISTRO_NAME`.  This variable is injected into the WSL environment automatically.

  Caveats:  You could always (pathologically) create this variable name on any system, leading to false positives.

  More importantly, there are cases when this variable will *not* be available, such as if you `su - $USER`.

There are certainly more (e.g. see if `$(which powershell.exe)` is executable), but the above should give you some idea of the various approaches.

Comment: as somebody who most of the time compiles his own kernel, i second the warning for point 2. Other approach: can't u just check whether u can access filepath C:\ ??? WSL should have all native windows commands and paths. might aswell check for cmd-command

Comment: @clockw0rk Sort of, `C:` doesn't quite work since it's `/mnt/c` in WSL, but that mount can (a) be easily changed by `/etc/wsl.conf` or (b) disabled entirely using the same. And yes, `cmd.exe`, `powershell.exe` (mentioned as one of the "more" options in the last line), `notepad.exe` ... all could be used, but only if Interop isn't disabled. If it is, then that method won't work either.

Comment: In WSLv2 with any of the Kali, Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 22.04 distros, `which powershell.exe` works for a normal user, but not for a user who's just become root with `sudo su`.

Comment: @AJM Sure, clearly I didn't go into the caveats on the "certainly more" section.  There are false positives and negatives with every option.  If `$(which powershell.exe)` was without issue, it would have been listed as a better option ;-).

Answer (score 9):

Check the output of

```bash
cat /proc/version
```

and

```bash
cat /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease
```

For example:

```bash
if [[ $(grep -i Microsoft /proc/version) ]]; then
echo "Bash is running on WSL"
fi
```

Comment: I made a slight edit since the string can be either "Microsoft" or "microsoft" depending on the WSL version.  Also note that this will work for most users, but WSL2 can use a custom kernel, and there's no requirement that kernel name includes that string.

Answer (score 3):

If you have systemd enabled you can try

```
systemd-detect-virt
```

this should return

```
wsl
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but under WSL the command `lscpu` shows a line:

- `Hypervisor vendor:   Windows Subsystem for Linux`

It does this as both an ordinary user and under `sudo su` .

Comment: To me, this does output `Hypervisor vendor:               Microsoft`.